# Hosting web application built with docker on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, codeigniter-3, lamp

I have a web application built with Codeigniter. I recently implemented Docker in the application on the localhost. Now how do I deploy modified application and the docker containers on the server.

I have provided my docker-compose file below.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
myapp:
 image: docker.io/bitnami/codeigniter:3
 container_name: app-backend
ports:
 - '8000:8000'
volumes:
  - '.:/app'  
depends_on:
 - mariadb
mariadb:
 image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3
 container_name: app-marriadb
volumes:
  - app_dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
ports:
 - '3307:3306'
environment:
 - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
volumes:
 app_dbdata:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of deploying is not different from what we follow while deploying a web app or website without docker. Only the following changes are additional which needs to be done on the server.

I changed the virtual host as shown below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog logs/docker.example.com_error.log
    CustomLog logs/docker.example.com_access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And then made the following changes to Apache

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_http
$ systemctl restart apache2
```

You should have be able to access your website or web app from the internet with a domain name. You can also add https with letsencrypt and the steps are the same.